# Как загрузить файл на PHP, POST запросом помощью C#

Tags: php, c#

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи !

Требуется загрузить файл (file.bin) на скрипт POST запросом посредством C#.
Про заливку файла на FTP вообще не говорить, нужно именно на скрипт.
Буду рад любой помощи.

Сам PHP скрипт:

```
<?php

$file1 = $_FILES['data']['tmp_name'];
$name = basename($_FILES['data']['name']);

$dir1 = mkdir('up/');
$dir='up/';

$id=$_POST['data2'];

if (!file_exists($file1))
{
    echo "ERROR";
}
else
{
    move_uploaded_file($file1, $dir.$name);

    echo "OK <br>";
    echo $id;
}

?>
```

Заранее больше спасибо!

Comment: Очень, знаете, проблематично понять в чем же у вас проблема, если код отправки файла вы не показали.

Comment: Проблема в том , что кода нету , а гугл не помог.
Я хотел что бы дали готовое решение

Comment: Тут сервис вопросов, а не сервис "сделайте за меня".

Comment: я попросил пример как это делается дать.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post

Comment: Гугл "C# post request"

Comment: Вопрос как написать клиент на C# (http post request), который отправит локальный файл на заданный php сервер? Или как отправить файл, используя C# на клиенте и php на сервере (ограничиваясь по-видимому http протоколом)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
new WebClient().UploadFile(address, fileName);
```

параметр `data2` допишите в url, как `?data2=ssomething`

Comment: Если правильно помню особенности PHP, то это не сработает. data2 в его коде берется из $_POST - в неё попадают данные **только** из содержимого запроса. Параметры указанные в url туда не попадают. Здесь от клиента ожидается multipart/form-data. К сожалению, WebClient всё ещё не имеет методов для работы с этим типом содержимого запросов. Нужно либо переделывать PHP-скрипт на сервере, либо использовать другие классы для работы с HTTP.